# jQuery data attribute updates only after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery code which should print all selected checkboxes:

```
$('.engagement-type').on('click', function () {
    var engagementTypes = $('.engagement-type').parent().find('[data-checkbox="checked"]');
    console.log(engagementTypes);
});
```

12 checkboxes are in the table:

```
<td>
    <input name="EngagementTypes[0].EngagementTypeId" 
      id="EngagementTypes_0__EngagementTypeId" 
      type="hidden" value="1" data-val-required="The Engagement field is required." 
      data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Engagement must be a number.">

    <span class="pull-left">
        <div class="engagement-type" data-checkbox="checked">
            <input name="EngagementTypes[0].IsSelected" 
              id="EngagementTypes_0__IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true" 
              data-val-required="The IsSelected field is required." 
              data-val="true">
            <input name="EngagementTypes[0].IsSelected" type="hidden" value="false">
        </div>
    </span>
    Audit
</td>
```

After first click on the checkbox I get empty list of selected engagement types. The first checkbox appears only after the second checkbox is checked. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: There's clearly more code at play here, something is updating the `data` attributes but you haven't shown that. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: Unsolicited protip: Your form isn't accessible--you don't have labels on your inputs.

Comment: The `class="engagement-type"` element is also the same element with the `data-checkbox="checked"` attribute on it.  It is unnecessary to go to the parent and find the element again.

Answer (score 0):

```
var engagementTypes = $('.engagement-type').parent().find('[data-checkbox="checked"]')
```

This will only work if you click on the div engagement-type. But if you click on one of the checkboxes in the div the parent is the one with the checkbox attribute, so he will not find another within this.

So you should always select

```
var elementYouWant = $('.engagement-type')
```

Then check if the data attribute is checked.

```
var dataElement = elementYouWant.data();
if (dataElement['checkbox'] == "checked") {
   console.log("Oh yeah baby")
}
```

Ofcourse if there are multiple, you should do this in a loop for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

As @T.J. Crowder mentioned, there must be additional code which you do not have provided.
At least the part which will set the data-checkbox = checked.

I would assume to use the checkbox state itself like:

```
$('.engagement-type').on('click', function () {

    var engagementTypesChecked = $('.engagement-type').parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    console.log(engagementTypesChecked);

});
```